# Кастомный адаптер и корутины

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, coroutine

При попытке заполнить ListView с помощью кастомного адаптера получаю пустой список, не могу разобраться в чём ошибка ?

> HeroesAdapter.kt

```
class HeroesAdapter(context: Context, heroes: List<TestHero>): BaseAdapter() {
    private val context = context
    private val heroes = heroes

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return heroes.count()
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return heroes[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

           // categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_heroes, null)
        val categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_heroes, parent, false)
           // val categoryImage: ImageView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.heroesImageView)
            val categoryText: TextView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.textHeroView)
            val category = heroes[position]

            categoryText.text = category.global.name

            return categoryView

    }
}
```

> HeroesActivity

```
class HeroesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var adapter : ArrayAdapter<TestHero>
    lateinit var adapt: ArrayAdapter<String>
    lateinit var heroesAdapt : HeroesAdapter
    var listHero = ArrayList<TestHero>()
    private val TAG = "HeroesActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_heroes)



       // val adapterr = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,)


        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            LinkedList<TestHero>())
       // heroesListView.adapter = adapter

        adapt = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            LinkedList<String>())
        //heroesListView.adapter = adapt


        getCurrentData()

        heroesAdapt = HeroesAdapter(this, listHero)
        heroesListView.adapter = heroesAdapt

    }

    private fun getCurrentData() {
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiRequest::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.herList().awaitResponse()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val data = response.body()!!
                Log.d(TAG, data.toString())

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                   // adapter.add(data.global.name)
                    adapt.add(data.global.platform)

                    listHero.add(data)

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

> activity_heroes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HeroesActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/heroesListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> list_hero_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/heroesImageView"
        android:layout_width="426dp"
        android:layout_height="231dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/wraith_apex_legends" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHeroView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wraith"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Вы добавляете элемент в список `listHero.add(data)`, но не сообщаете адаптеру, что список изменился. Для этого нужно вызвать метод `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Кроме этого, рекомендую сделать `val listHero` вместо `var listHero`, чтобы случайно не изменить ссылку на список. Иначе все может поломаться: в адаптере будет один список, а изменять вы будете другой.

Comment: @Vadik Я же правильно понимаю, что `heroesAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged()` я добавляю после `listHero.add(data)`в `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`

Comment: Дело в том что после добавления я стал получать ошибку `categoryView.findViewById(R.id.textHeroView) must not be null` думаю это связано из-за того что не успевают обновиться данные

Comment: Да, верно, сразу после добавления можно вызвать nofity. А это у вас уже другая ошибка. И она похоже связана с тем, что вы ищете `R.id.textHeroView` почему-то в разметке `activity_heroes.xml`, а не `list_hero_view.xml`.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `R.layout.activity_heroes` на `R.layout.list_hero_view` в классе `HeroesAdapter.kt`.

Comment: @Vadik Да действительно, невнимательность, огромное спасибо вам за помощь и ответ, хорошего вам дня

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы обновить данные в списке, вызовите:

```kotlin
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```